# How do I express the phrase "disorderly conduct" using a verb?

Tags: word-choice

How do I express the phrase *disorderly conduct* using a verb? For example:

> The man was thrown in the slammer for **diorderly conduct**.

I would like to know formal and informal ways to say that.

Comment: drinking? ( :-P )

Comment: *...for conducting himself in a disorderly manner?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's an English verb with the specific sense of "conducting oneself in a disorderly manner". Presumably in OP's context we're looking for a *continuous / gerund* verb form anyway, so we can say...

> *He was arrested for XXXing*

It's worth noting that idiomatically, we're much more likely to say *He was arrested for **rape, theft, murder*** (*nouns* referencing *actions*) rather than the relevant *verb* forms ***...raping, thieving, murdering***.

The exact definition of "disorderly conduct" is more a matter of law than of language as such, but there ***is*** a (relatively uncommon today) verb with the specific sense of "fighting in public, engaging in affray". And since that's the *primary* example of disorderly conduct, I think we're pretty close with...

> *He was arrested* [*for (public) **brawling***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for%20public%20brawling%22)

---

> [<sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brawling)
> **brawl** *- to fight in a rough, noisy, uncontrolled way*

Comment: "*He was arrested for XXXing.* → *He was arrested for **being** disorderly.*

Comment: True. Though I'm not sure we can really equate *He was arrested for **drinking,*** say, with *He was arrested for **being drunk / drunkenness***.